# JS Login pop up is not working within Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the trim text code with jquery below to make the users login to my website when they click `more` to see more text content, and I have signup pop up that will show up for users who are not logged in already to my website.

But the pop up is not working, and it takes the users to the sign up html page instead of showing the pop up. The pope is working fine if I put `<a class="open-popup" id="sign-in" href="/users/register"?>Sign in</a>` any where outside the jquery

below is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('#transcript');

    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).html();        
        if(t.length < 400) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0, 400) + '<span>... </span><a class="open-popup" id="sign-in" href="/users/register"?>Sign in</a>' +'<span style="display:none;">' + t.slice(400, t.length) + ' <a href="#" class="less"></a></span>' 
        );

    }); 

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
</script>
```

Popup code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var id = null;
    var target = null;

    $('.open-popup').magnificPopup({

        type:'ajax',
        midClick: true,
```

.....till the end of the code.

I think the fix is very simple, but I could not pin point what is it. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: If your popup code is before the other code `$('.open-popup')` won't exist yet

Comment: Could you recreate your code inside the code-runner?

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain more? the pop code is a JS and it is in an external file. '<a class="open-popup" id="sign-in" href="/users/register"?>Sign in</a>' is working everywhere but when I put it inside the trim J query, it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl you were right, I had to mode the Popup JS script to  the end of page to make it work. Thanks!